# iterate through directory, sort and display items in alphabetical order

Tags: php

I'm using the FilesystemIterator to iterate through a directory called photos then create a hyperlink to each photo like this:

```
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('photos');
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileinfo) {
  echo "<span class='photos_hyperlink'><a href='displayPicture.php?img=$fileSystemIterator' target='_blank'>";
  echo $fileSystemIterator . "</a></span><br><br>";
}
```

This works, but items aren't in alphabetical order so to alphabetize them I'm trying to store them in an array, sort, then display. I'm missing something because nothing is being printed to the screen. Could anyone offer some advice on what I'm missing?

```
$photosArray = array();
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('photos');
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileinfo) {
    $photosArray[$fileinfo->getFilename()];
}

sort($photosArray);

foreach ($photosArray as $val) {
    echo "<span class='photos_hyperlink'><a href='displayPicture.php?img=$val' target='_blank'>";
    echo $val. "</a></span><br><br>";
}
```

Comment: `glob` will return an alphabetized list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `foreach` loop from:

```
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileinfo) {
    $photosArray[$fileinfo->getFilename()];
}
```

To:

```
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileinfo) {
    $photosArray[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You store filenames in array keys, not values.

```
$photosArray[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you are "assigning" the filename into the key of the array

```
$photosArray[$fileinfo->getFilename()];
```

Try change it to

```
$photosArray[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
```